# Facebook graph API does not return all posts for user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all user posts through Facebook graph API. But never get all of it.

When I tried it through the path: "me/posts" (with param limit=5000), I get all of the posts that wrote by the user (like I wanted), but not before specific date. Mean, in this way I am not getting any of the posts before specific date (in my case it was not before 29/01/2011).

When I tried it through the path: "me/feed" (with param limit=5000), I get all kind  of posts from my profile wall even posts that not the user wrote and posts from start of my Facebook (2007).
But, this result is missing some of my posts through time. When I roll in my old post on my profile page I can see many posts that I wrote but its not in the result.

When I tried it through the fql:

```
"SELECT post_id, actor_id, created_time, updated_time,  action_links, permalink, message, action_links FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() LIMIT 5000"
```

I get the same result as when I tried with the path: "me/feed". And the same missing posts is missing.

Is anybody else had this problem too?

#### Update:

I am sorry that I wasn't clear enough. My interest is only on the posts that current user wrote, not on his friends posts. I know that sometimes I can get from Facebook only mixed posts - like when I ask for the path: "me/feed". But, my intention was to filter them on my server.

The posts that missing from the data (and I can see on my wall) is my post, not my friend's posts.

Comment: I'm also facing this problem, with my own profile. If anyone has any insights, please help.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when your friends have set their privacy settings so that their posts aren't made available via the Facebook platform. That's probably why you are seeing the difference.