# Facebook Graph Api json missing posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an web app, which connect to facebook, to get posts, and other stuff liked by users. I have problem with getting all posts from user page using news feed(home connection of Grap API).

When getting access token in my app for user, I ask for read_stream, user_activities and offline access permissions. Then, when I use that token, to get json feed for

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/me/home/?access_token=<retrived_access_token>
```

some posts(which are show on user page) are missing. I found that posts of my friends, which can be seen only by their friends, are not shown in that feed. The same issue is with posts of users which current I am subscribing.

I was searching on that for a while, and I found, that when I use link from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ to get my news feed, there are much more posts. It's seems to use a token generated for test console app for facebook api.

Then I tried to generate access token which would give me similar results using http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET. But even when I give to generated token  all possible permissions I could not get it working good, there were still some missing posts.

I read answer in that post, [Facebook graph API does not return all posts for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736338/facebook-graph-api-does-not-return-all-posts-for-user), which suggested, that this is because of permissions set by my people who publish posts, who  don't want their data to be retrieved by an app. I run some quick test, and I found that changing that setting is working( when somebody change that setting her posts will disappear from both feeds - that using my app token for user, and that under link on api reference page), but it's not the case.

It seems that this token generated on api reference page have an special permission.

I really need to get as much posts from user page as possible. I know that I will not get those blocked by their author, but as many of my users subscribe other users I really need to get access to kind of posts shown on user page.

I also read [Facebook graph API: feeds missing in json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622096/facebook-graph-api-feeds-missing-in-json-response) but it was also not helpfull.

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: I've managed to answer most of my questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214535/what-is-the-difference-between-feed-posts-and-statuses-in-facebook-graph-api/7983267#7983267), however I would still award the bounty to any clear and helpful answer which can complement that information.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to get a full list of posts from the feed / home Graph API, but you can use FQL to query the `stream` table to get almost every post made by friends, here is a quick example of how you would do that with the javascript sdk:

```js
var query = 'SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key = "others"';
FB.api('fql', {'q': query}, function(posts) { console.log(posts.data); });
```

This will get you the post ids, which you can then use with graph api to fetch the rest of the post info. Or you can get the full list of fields here, you can't select * in FQL so you'll have to list each piece you want and then get comments and likes and names separately.

Comment: also, FQL supports LIMIT which you'll need to add to get more results

Comment: do you know why its almost impossible? I can't seem to find a clear answer.

Comment: @studgeek it is impossible because Facebook refuses to return all posts unfiltered and because friends have privacy settings that block objects from applications specifically even if they are not blocked on regular facebook

Answer (score 1):

There is an assigned/medium bug on this at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228057243915183. You can bump up the priority by subscribing and indicating you can reproduce it.

Also see http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/231621496918030 where Facebook has said "the stream table and me/graph have limitations. See the documentation for more info. We're trying to make this more clear in the future." Personally I don't think there is really any more info in the documentation though.